# Inequality for roots of a polynomial

Tags: probability, number-theory, analysis

I am trying to find the Lundberg Coefficient for mixed exponential. I solve the following polynomial in $r$;
$$\frac{\lambda}{c}\left(\frac{p \alpha}{\alpha-r}+\frac{(1-p)\beta}{\beta-r} -1\right)=r$$
for $0<\alpha <\beta$ and $\lambda,c>0$,  $0<p<1$ with 
$ c> \lambda \left(\frac{p}{\alpha}+\frac{1-p}{\beta}\right)$ and $p<\frac{\beta}{\beta-\alpha}$.
I get $r=0$ as a solution and two roots of the quadratic
$$cr^2+\left(-\lambda +c\alpha +c\beta \right)r- p\lambda \alpha +p \lambda \beta +\lambda \alpha -c\alpha \beta=0$$
given as
$$r_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\alpha +\beta -\tfrac{\lambda}{c} \pm \sqrt{\left(\beta-\alpha-\tfrac{\lambda}{c}\right)^2+4p\tfrac{\lambda}{c}(\beta-\alpha)}\right)$$
denote $r^+$ for the bigger root and $r^-$ for the smaller. It seems that the roots satisfy:

$$r=0<r^-<\alpha <r^+<\beta$$

and so $r^-$ is the solution, since $r^+>\alpha$, its not in the domain of convergence of the mgf. 
Is this true for these kinds of polynomials in general?, that is do the roots of

$$\frac{\lambda}{c}\left(\frac{p \alpha}{\alpha-x}+\frac{(1-p)\beta}{\beta-x} -1\right)=x$$
always satisfy
$$x_0=0<x_1<\alpha <x_2< \beta ?$$
I'm not sure if this fits under number theory but I'm putting it there too. If it's not appropriate please remove it

Comment: You have $c r^2$ instead of $-c r^2$ and $-\alpha \lambda$ instead of $-p \alpha \lambda$. If the quadratic polynomial is $c P(r)$, we have
$$P(0) = (q \alpha + p \beta) \mu - \alpha \beta < 0, \\
P(\alpha) = p (\beta - \alpha) \mu > 0, \\
P(\beta) = -q (\beta - \alpha) \mu < 0,$$
where $\mu = \lambda/c$ and $q = 1 - p$.
That means there are two real roots, one between $0$ and $\alpha$ and another one between $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The condition $p < \beta/(\beta - \alpha)$ is not needed.

Comment: You mean there should be $p$ that I forgot to write? I think the sign might be a typo too; I'll fix it when I can

Comment: @Maxim i worked on it and youre right! all works out, ty